# How do I change the style of points that were created with pointToLayer in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, symbology, style

I'd like to change the style of certain points based on events, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/221te82q/1/) for an example.

```
var points = new L.geoJson(pointsData, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    if (feature.properties.name === "Point1") {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 10,
        fillColor: "blue",
        color: "black"
      });

    } else if (feature.properties.name === "Point2") {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 10,
        fillColor: "green",
        color: "white"
      });

    } else if (feature.properties.name === "Point3") {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 10,
        fillColor: "orange",
        color: "purple"
      });
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

In the above example, how would I change the style of, say, `Point1` after it's been created?

I haven't found anything in the documentation, or online.

Is it possible?

---

I ended up splitting the geojson up for each point, and created a function that returns a new geojson object.

```
point1Data = {
    ...
};

point2Data = {
    ...
};

function createPoint(pointData, radius, fill, stroke) {

    return new L.geoJson(pointData, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: radius,
                fillColor: fill,
                color: stroke,
            });
        }
    });
}

point1.createPoint(point1Data, 10, "red", "black").addTo(map);
point1.remove();
point1 = createPoint(point1Data, 10, "black", "red").addTo(map);
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/221te82q/3/) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [eachLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-eachlayer) to loop through your GeoJSON features and [setStyle](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#featuregroup-setstyle) to change the feature's style.

Here's a [tweaked version of your fiddle that waits a second then makes Point1 red](https://jsfiddle.net/221te82q/2/).

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I ended up splitting the geojson up for each point, and then created a function that returns a new geojson object. I edited my question to show. Is there anything wrong with doing it that way, or is your example the preferred way?

Comment: Glad to help. Either way works. I don't think there's a best practice for this and I wouldn't worry about optimizing this or using a clever solution until you have a lot of data to manage. Go with what makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 3):

To set your points style after some action on your layer point (e.g. after click), you can do it with `onEachFeature` function. To get along with your code the function can look like this:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
        if(feature.properties.name === "Point1") {
          this.setStyle({fillColor: "black", fillOpacity: 1});
        }
      else if(feature.properties.name === "Point2") {
          this.setStyle({fillColor: "green", fillOpacity: 1});
        }
      else if(feature.properties.name === "Point3") {
          this.setStyle({fillColor: "red", fillOpacity: 1});
        };
    });
}
```

Point will change it's color after you click on it. 
Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/OWrgVd

Comment: Thanks! So the `onEachFeature` property can be used for events? That's cool. I thought it was used to do something with the data immediately.

Comment: @geogeogeo yes you can assign here a function that fires after some action (in example click or mouseover) or just after some time interval